# Double integral in polar coordinate

Tags: calculus

How to evaluate the integral in polar coordinates

$$\int_0^1\int_y^1 e^{x^2}dxdy.$$ I know this integral is equal to $$\int\int e^{r^2 cos^2 \theta} r dr d\theta$$ But I have trouble evaluating the limits. I mean the second integral limits are $x, 1$ this implies $1=rsin\theta$, so $r=1/sin\theta$, can I say that the upper limit of $r$ is $1$? Or it evaluates as $1/sin\theta$? and what about the lower limit $x$.

Comment: Do you mean the integral $$\int_{0}^{1}\left(\int_{y}^{1}e^{x^2}\mathrm{d}x\right)\mathrm{d}y$$?

Comment: No, I mean $\int_0^1\int_y^1(e^{x^2})dy dx$. @CunyiNan

Comment: It is odd that the inner integral is $\int_{y}^{1}e^{x^2}\mathrm{d}y$ because the lower bound and the variable are the same $y$.

Comment: Yes, I know something wrong! @CunyiNan

Comment: So, what are the ranges of $x$ and $y$? Like $y\leq x\leq 1$ and $0\leq y\leq1$?

Comment: I modified it, can you help me find the limits? @CunyiNan

Comment: If you sketch the integration region you should find it's $0\le\theta\le\pi/4,\,0\le r\le\sec\theta$. If you integrate out $r$ first, your double integral should be $(e-1)/2$.

Comment: How can I find it? why if x=y implies r=0? @J.G.

Comment: $x=y$ corresponds to $\theta=\pi/4$, except $x=y=0$, which corresponds to $r=0$.

Comment: You do realize, I’m sure, that the integral is most easily done by applying Fubini and changing the order of integration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking to cover this area

[image: fig1]

so your integral is

$$\boxed{I = \int_0^{\pi/4} \int_0^{1/\cos\theta} e^{r^2 cos^2 \theta}\, r \,{\rm d}r\, {\rm d}\theta} $$

You find this by looking at $r \cos \theta = 1$ and solving for $r$